# How to draw real-time line graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code to draw a real-time scatter plot using matplotlib based on references. How do i get a real-time line graph instead?

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axis([0, 100, -10, 10])
plt.ion()
plt.show()

ts_start = time.time()

## perpetual loop code
    p_x = int(int(time.time())-int(ts_start))
    p_y = mynum # keeps getting generated in the loop code
    plt.scatter(p_x, p_y)
    plt.plot(p_x, p_y)
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axis([0, 100, -10, 10])
plt.ion()
plt.show()
ydata = [0]
line, = plt.plot(ydata)

ts_start = time.time()

## perpetual loop code
    p_x = int(int(time.time())-int(ts_start))
    p_y = mynum # keeps getting generated in the loop code
    ydata.append(p_y)
    line.set_xdata(np.arange(len(ydata)))
    line.set_ydata(ydata)
    plt.draw()
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: You can also look into blitting which will help with performance (so you don't have to re-render all of the text every time).